# Performing extended merge sort containing multiple lists

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

Recently I have been working on some data structures to record my daily activity.

My approach is to create a tag system of sort that resembles a tree. Like a "Monetary" class can contain subclasses like "Allowance", "Food and drinks" and "Rent". Each of those tags might contain even more child tags, like "Allowance" will have "Yearly allowance", "Monthly allowance" and "Daily allowance".

Each of these child tags will contain a reference (I'm doing this in Java by the way, meaning pointer arithmetic is not allowed) to other child tags before and after it, like "Monthly allowance" will have `previousSibling` point to "Yearly allowance" and `nextSibling` point to "Daily allowance".

Each tag will also contain some instances (lets call them "events") recording specific actions like in tag "Allowance" there might be an instance that record the amount of money received yearly from a bank's interest.

All of these are fine and I have code them already but when displaying the data, I got stuck. What i wanted is to sum up the money make and the money spend on a particular interval of time, say from April 21st to April 22nd. I plan to sort them and then just pick out the range of events that are between April 21st and 22nd. That's ok when you are dealing with only the events in a single tag. What I want is to gather all events in all tags that are a child tag of some specified tag, for example I want to gather all events that are in "Allowance" tag, together with it's 3 child tags' events.

I plan to approach this sorting problem with a merge sort approach: first I sort the events of "Yearly allowance", "Monthly allowance" and "Daily allowance". Then I sort "Allowance", "Food and drinks", "Rent" and then "Monetary". Assuming we're sorting Allowance with its childs already sorted, what I need to do kinda resembles this:

```
ArrayList<Event> list = new ArrayList<>();

//assuming yearlyAllowance.events is an ArrayList<Event>
list.add(yearlyAllowance.events.get(0));
list.add(monthlyAllowance.events.get(0));
list.add(dailyAllowance.events.get(0));
list.add(allowance.events.get(0));

//helper method
sortByTime(list);
ArrayList<Event> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

while(!list.isEmpty()){
  finalList.add(list.get(0));
  Event tmpEvent = list.get(0);
  list.remove(0);
  //slipping the next event in tmpEvent in, should take O(ln(n)) time on average as list is sorted and we're binary inserting them
  if(tmpEvent.nextSibling != null){
    insertBinary(list, tmpEvent.nextSibling);
  }
}
```

So here, I'm basically doing merge sort on several lists at once, meaning at each stage, I merge a bunch of sorted lists together. I'm following this method because I can mark each tag as being sorted or not, which means I don't have to re-sort everything, like re-sorting Allowance tag after I have sorted Monetary class if you were to simply gather all events from Monetary tag and its child tags' events and sort them.

Is there a better way to do this? I'm doing this as an android application so i really need the speed in order to display the information to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to sort all events since you only need an interval of events. The better approach would be finding the events in the specified interval and add them into a list before sorting. You just need to have an if statement before adding the events into your final list.